# Questions (intuitive) about circuits and the flow of electrons

Tags: electric-circuits

Why don't electrons accelerate in a circuit? If there is a potential difference and the electron moves in the circuit a force is exerted on it. Why does that force produce no acceleration, keeping the current constant?

If we add a resistor to a circuit why is the resistance 'spread' over the circuit? Is it because electrons moving faster in the areas of lower resistance would create charge imbalances at places in the conductor?